# Woke uo this morning to find out that nautilus icon are bigger

Tags: nautilus

After an update last night, login to my Laptop and open Nautilus, to find out that all icons are bigger than usual settings. please kindly assist me

Comment: Can't you just zoom out ctrl + -

Answer (score 0):

First, open nautilus.

Then, click on a blank space in nautilus.

Finally, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the size of the icons; press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the size of the icons.

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and scroll up with the mouse-wheel or touchpad to increase the size of the icons; press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and scroll down with the mouse-wheel or touchpad decrease the size of the icons